# how to disable android connection to local internet network

Tags: android

apparently in my country it's not in the companies best intrest to disconnect you from thier cellular connection (so they could charge for more)

i have read about how to in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html 
where there was an overhead of infomation
i already built some apps but it seems to b something i cant really understand his concept can someone guide me ? give a link for where to read this info please .

I want to program a little app which in a click on a button will disconnect from the local internet cellular provider (just there internet ' i will still b able to phone other pep).

Comment: I have touble figuring out what it exactly is that you want to know. Is this question programming-related? Or is it about the configuration of your phone from a user perspective? Maybe you should rephrase your question :-)

Comment: not sure why you need an app for that, you can already turn off the phone functionality in the Android network settings. Or, when you press the power button on i.e. Nexus One, it will give you the option for 'Airplane mode' directly, which is the same as well. There are multiple ways to turn your phone off the phone network.

Comment: I am using Motorola milestone , I tried by myself with the given software with no successes and therefore called the company where one of there employees told me there's no application inside the given phone who support such a thing therefore it will be very helpful for me as a developer and for other's who being ripped off by the cellular companies to get this app , the thing is they charge you for using the internet where the phone make connection automatic without the user idea and the only ways to shut it down shuts also your availability as a customer who only wants to use the phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/) open-source project. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: thanku it even has an API if i want to do it in my lang :) you just saved me a lot of money thanku :)